# first few values of instantiated PRNG are close to 0

Tags: f#

Friends, the first (maybe a couple) values generated from the following PRNG are either 0 or close to it no matter the seed. Is there a way this can be primed with a constructor or even better, without having to burn a couple of values?

```
type PRNGXXX(seed) =
    let mutable s : uint64[] =  Array.zeroCreate 2

    let rotl(x : uint64, k : int) =
        (x <<< k) ||| (x >>> (64 - k))

    do s.[1] <- uint64 seed

    let sample() : uint64 =
        let s0 : uint64 = s.[0]
        let mutable s1 : uint64 = s.[1]
        let result : uint64 = s0 + s1

        s1 <- s1 ^^^ s0
        s.[0] <- rotl(s0, 24) ^^^ s1 ^^^ (s1 <<< 16)
        s.[1] <- rotl(s1, 37)

        result

    member x.NextDouble() = (float (sample())) / float System.UInt64.MaxValue
```

Translated from C++ at http://xoshiro.di.unimi.it/xoroshiro128plus.c

```
#include <stdint.h>

static inline uint64_t rotl(const uint64_t x, int k) {
    return (x << k) | (x >> (64 - k));
}

static uint64_t s[2];

uint64_t next(void) {
    const uint64_t s0 = s[0];
    uint64_t s1 = s[1];
    const uint64_t result = s0 + s1;

    s1 ^= s0;
    s[0] = rotl(s0, 24) ^ s1 ^ (s1 << 16); // a, b
    s[1] = rotl(s1, 37); // c

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the comments of the link you posted: "The state must be seeded so that it is not everywhere zero. If you have a 64-bit seed, we suggest to seed a splitmix64 generator and use its output to fill s." What you're doing is seeding just the lower half of the 128-bit state, so the upper half is zero. Result: the first call to `next()` will return *precisely the seed you put in* (notice how `result` is calculated *before* `s0` and `s1` were mixed together: at the time of the first call, `s0` is 0 and `s1` is your initial seed).

Two solutions: one is to modify your PRNG class to take *two* uint64 values, like so:

```
type PRNGXXX(seed0, seed1) =
    let mutable s : uint64[] =  Array.zeroCreate 2
    // ...    
    do
        s.[0] <- uint64 seed0
        s.[1] <- uint64 seed1
    // ...
```

The other is to do as the original code's authors suggest and use a [splitmix64 function](https://github.com/svaarala/duktape/blob/master/misc/splitmix64.c) to get two 64-bit values out of one single 64-bit seed. Here's the C version of that algorithm from that link (public domain):

```
uint64_t next() {
    uint64_t z = (x += UINT64_C(0x9E3779B97F4A7C15));
    z = (z ^ (z >> 30)) * UINT64_C(0xBF58476D1CE4E5B9);
    z = (z ^ (z >> 27)) * UINT64_C(0x94D049BB133111EB);
    return z ^ (z >> 31);
}
```

I suggest using two 64-bit values as your seed, instead of just one 64-bit value that's run through a splitmix, because in the latter case you'll only *truly* have 64 bits of entropy rather than 128.

Comment: problem solved. thanks. does msft open source implementation of System.Random()? googling around suggests mersenne_twister_engine but can't seem to find the implementation.

Comment: .Net Framework implementation: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/random.cs and .Net Core implementation: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Random.cs